# How to approximate the result of a tetration

Tags: tetration

I'm trying to calculate the result of some tetrations of 2 but my program can't get to 2↑↑6, it just takes to long.

So i wanted to ask if there's a way to approximate the result of a tetration, even a rough approximation is enough for me.

Comment: This number is about $$10^{10^{19727.7804}}$$

Comment: [This](http://mrob.com/pub/comp/hypercalc/hypercalc-javascript.html) is a calculator for tetration